# Set a default segment for Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I set up a segment that contains the data that my colleagues and I will want to be looking at 90% of the time. The **All sessions** segment contains superfluous data that we will generally not be interested in. However, every time I go to the GA, the **All sessions** segment is selected. I already know how to change/add the segments that I am looking at but is there a way for my segment to already be selected each time I arrive at GA?

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing I know of is creating a "shortcut" link which saves the segment that was applied.

> #### Shortcuts
>
> Using shortcuts provides fast access to your most commonly viewed reports straight from the Home tab. When you save your report as a shortcut, all of the report configurations will be stored as well. This can include applied filters, advanced segments, dimensions, and more.
>
> To begin using shortcuts, click the "Shortcut" button on the toolbar of the report you wish to save. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2676996?hl=en)

When I create a shortcut with a segment applied, I get a quick link to that report with that segment at the top of the left hand navigation.   It doesn't seem to apply that segment to all reports from that point, however.

It does not appear that adding a shortcut changes anything in the URL. Because of that, creating a bookmark with a segment does not appear to be a possibility.

[image]

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the button to add "Shorcut"? I can't find it in interface July 2017 interface. I have seen something else that looks similar but not sure if it's the same thing. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Basj  It is still in the same spot.  I added a screenshot of creating the shortcut with red circles around the parts of the page I touched to make it happen.

Comment: Thanks @StephenOstermiller for the screenshot. On my interface, there is no "Shortcut", but a "Save" button instead. In `Customisation` (funnily on your interface, it's with a `z` on mine it's `...sation` with a s!), there is no "Shortcut" but "Saved reports". [Drawback](https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Google-Analytics-Reports/Saved-Reports/td-p/1170553#)

Comment: See here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JWBT.jpg

Comment: @Basj looks like you have a new interface or something meant for smaller screens.   I'm not sure where it is on yours.  It could be under the "save" button or even under the "share" menu right next to it.

Answer (score 3):

As of 4.25.16, you can now bookmark "shortcuts" in GA. So, for example, if you've applied many custom segments, save those changes as a "shortcut", and then bookmark the "shortcut", your bookmark will go directly to the "shortcut" view and you'll see your segments in place.

Answer (score 1):

So you create a shortcut to some data and you apply your segment to it (e.g. My shortcut is Landing Pages, and the segment I applied to the shortcut has a filter on it that cleans out spam).  So the problem then is that every time you exit it out from it and come back in later, the segment will not be applied and you have go into the list of segments and click the one you want.  To avoid this, go to your shortcuts, apply the segment you want and then click "Save" in the upper left corner (above the current segment, where is says 
Save / Email / Export / Add to Dashboard

The segment you chose should be applied every time you go into the shortcut thereafter.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution that will have the result you want is to make a new 'view' of your account and apply the filters you want to that. (very important - keep an unfiltered view as well)